# scale columns of an xts object

Tags: r, for-loop, xts, apply

I often deal with data in `xts` formats, and frequently must scale them (say to be equal to 100 on some date).  I presently do this using a function, which works using a `for-loop` -- however this does not seem very *functional*.

Here's how i do it now:

```
df1 <- data.frame(rnorm(100), runif(100), 1:100*rnorm(100))
dfx <- xts(df1, order.by = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), by='mon', length.out=100))

dfxColScl <- function(dfrm, pos=1, idx = 100)
{
    scaledDF <- dfrm
    for (i in 1:ncol(dfrm)) {
        scaledDF[, i] <- dfrm[,i] / as.numeric(dfrm[pos, i]) * idx
    }
    return(scaledDF)
}
```

Is there some clever `apply` type function that is the `R` way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sweep` can be used to divide a matrix by a row.

```
dfx.scaled2 <- sweep(100*dfx, 2, dfx[1], "/")
all.equal(dfx.scaled, dfx.scaled2) # same result as @Joshua
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice. I assumed `sweep` wouldn't work without using `coredata(dfx[1])` but the internal call to `array` takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `apply.daily`.  Note that you still have to use `coredata` on the row you want to divide by because xts/zoo operations always align by index before performing the operation.

```
dfx.scaled <- apply.daily(dfx, function(x) x/coredata(dfx[1,])*100)
```

Comment: +1, thanks. so if this were monthly data, i'd use apply.monthly?

Comment: @ricardo: In your example, `dfx` *was* monthly and `apply.daily` worked. It works because the index for `dfx` is Date.

Comment: i beg your pardon -- i didn't try it before i asked. I infer from this that `apply.daily` will work in all cases then?

Comment: @ricardo: it will work in all cases that the object's index is a `Date` object. It may work when the index is `yearmon` or `yearqtr`, but I'm not sure. It certainly won't work if the index has multiple observations per day because `apply.daily` will aggregate them into one observation per day.